# php curl_exec output to variable

Tags: php

i want to get return values in php $variables

what i get now is like this

**ok true 10007.20 cd3f2d61-c929-4a6e-a587-33878fb2b836 200**

while i want to get it in variable:

- $value1 = 'ok';
- $value2 = 'true';
- $value3 = '10007.20';

  ```
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://www.smsbox.com/SMSGateway/Services/Messaging.asmx/Http_SendSMS");

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,"username=".$username."&password=".$password."&customerId=".$cutomerId."&senderText=".$senderText."&messageBody=".$messageBody."&recipientNumbers=".$recipientNumbers."&defdate=&isBlink=false&isFlash=false");

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

  $content = curl_exec($ch);
  echo $content;

  curl_close ($ch);
  ```

echo htmlentities($content);

ok true 10005.20 4ce81f05-31cb-40c4-93e2-fd68bf50fc23   version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://itbsms.com/"> ok true 10006.20 3320429f-59b8-47fc-a49e-3e209a472b16 />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get the values in an array:

```
$values = explode(' ', $content);
```

Comment: Array ( [0] => version="1.0" [2] => encoding="utf-8"?> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" [4] => xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" [5] => xmlns="http://itbsms.com/"> [6] => [7] => ok [8] => [9] => true [10] => [11] => 10006.20 [12] => [13] => 3320429f-59b8-47fc-a49e-3e209a472b16 [14] => [15] => /> )

Comment: @user3127434 I assumed that `$content` was just `ok true 10007.20 cd3f2d61-c929-4a6e-a587-33878fb2b836 200`. You should have provided the full output of the `$content` variable. Please update your question.

Comment: i don't now about that! ... i update it now ... as i see it's XML ... is there away to get varaible from it ??

Comment: @user3127434 instead of doing `echo $content;` do `echo htmlentities($content);` and update the question with the exact output.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <SendingSMSResult xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://itbsms.com/"> <Message>ok</Message> <Result>true</Result> <NetPoints>10005.20</NetPoints> <messageId>4ce81f05-31cb-40c4-93e2-fd68bf50fc23</messageId> <RejectedNumbers /> </SendingSMSResult> version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://itbsms.com/"> ok true 10006.20 3320429f-59b8-47fc-a49e-3e209a472b16 />